# What model best suits optimizing for a real-time strategy game?

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

An article has been making the rounds lately discussing the use of genetic algorithms to optimize "build orders" in StarCraft II.

http://lbrandy.com/blog/2010/11/using-genetic-algorithms-to-find-starcraft-2-build-orders/

The initial state of a StarCraft match is pre-determined and constant. And like chess, decisions made in this early stage of the match have long-standing consequences to a player's ability to perform in the mid and late game. So the various opening possibilities or "build orders" are under heavy study and scrutiny. Until the circulation of the above article, computer-assisted build order creation probably wasn't as popularity as it has been recently.

My question is... **Is a genetic algorithm really the best way to model optimizing build orders?**

A build order is a sequence of actions. Some actions have prerequisites like, "You need building B before you can create building C, but you can have building A at any time." So a chromosome may look like AABAC.

I'm wondering if a genetic algorithm really is the best way to tackle this problem. Although I'm not too familiar with the field, I'm having a difficult time shoe-horning the concept of genes into a data structure that is a sequence of actions. These aren't independent choices that can be mixed and matched like a head and a foot. So what value is there to things like reproduction and crossing?

I'm thinking whatever chess AIs use would be more appropriate since the array of choices at any given time could be viewed as tree-like in a way.

Comment: Genes can't be mixed and matched freely either. (message written with my third nose)

Comment: define "best", as in *Is X really the best algorithm*.

Comment: define *"Most a..."* - ok ok: Algorithm have different comparable attributes: e.g. getting a better result, being easy to implement, guaranteeing a global optimum, requiring so much memory space or time. "best" could mean (a) excels in all categories (usually impossible), or (b) excels for a given weight function between the criteria.

Comment: Easy to implement? It feels like I'm shoe horning the chromosome/genes idea when the problem space could be more ... appropriately? defined using some other model, like a tree. Or something.

Comment: Sure, genetic algo's are usually more complex than a brute force, but they requrie less time for large problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TaslemGuy pointed out, Genetic Algorithms aren't guaranteed to be optimal, even though they usually give good results.

To get optimal results you would have to search through every possible combination of actions until you find the optimal path through the tree-like representation. However, doing this for StarCraft is difficult, since there are so many different paths to reach a goal. In chess you move a pawn from e2 to e4 and then the opponent moves. In StarCraft you can move a unit at instant x or x+1 or x+10 or ...

A chess engine can look at many different aspects of the board (e.g. how many pieces does it have and how many does the opponent have), to guide it's search. It can ignore most of the actions available if it knows that they are strictly worse than others.

For a build-order creator only time really matters. Is it better to build another drone to get minerals faster, or is it faster to start that spawning pool right away? Not as straightforward as with chess.

These kinds of decisions happen pretty early on, so you will have to search each alternative to conclusion before you can decide on the better one, which will take a *long* time.
If I were to write a build-order optimizer myself, I would probably try to formulate a heuristic that estimates how good (close the to the goal state) the current state is, just as chess engines do:

```
Score = a*(Buildings_and_units_done/Buildings_and_units_required) - b*Time_elapsed - c*Minerals - d*Gas + e*Drone_count - f*Supply_left
```

This tries to keep the score tied to the completion percentage as well as StarCraft common knowledge (keep your ressources low, build drones, don't build more supply than you need). The variables a to f would need tweaking, of course.

After you've got a heuristic that can somewhat estimate the worth of a situation, I would use [Best-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) or maybe [IDDFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) to search through the tree of possibilities.

**Edit**:

I recently found a [paper](http://skatgame.net/mburo/ps/aiide11-bo.pdf) that actually describes build order optimization in StarCraft, in real time even. The authors use [depth-first search](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Depth-first_search) with [branch and bound](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Branch_and_bound) and heuristics that estimate the minimum amount of effort required to reach the goal based on the tech tree (e.g. zerglings need a spawning pool) and the time needed to gather the required minerals.

Answer (score 3):

> Although I'm not too familiar with the field, I'm having a difficult time shoe-horning the concept of genes into a data structure that is a sequence of actions. These aren't independent choices that can be mixed and matched like a head and a foot. So what value is there to things like reproduction and crossing?

Hmm, that's a very good question. Perhaps the first few moves in Starcraft can indeed be performed in pretty much any order, since contact with the enemy is not as immediate as it can be in Chess, and therefore it is not as important to remember the order of the first few moves as it is to know which of the many moves are included in those first few. But the link seems to imply otherwise, which means the 'genes' are indeed not all that amenable to being swapped around, unless there's something cunning in the encoding that I'm missing.

On the whole, and looking at the link you supplied, I'd say that genetic algorithms are a poor choice for this situation, which could be accurately mathematically modelled in some parts and the search tree expanded out in others. They may well be better than an exhaustive search of the possibility space, but may not be - especially given that there are multiple populations and poorer ones are just wasting processing time.

However, what I mean by "a poor choice" is that it is inefficient relative to a more appropriate approach; that's not to say that it couldn't still produce 98% optimal results in under a second or whatever. In situations such as this where the brute force of the computer is useful, it is usually more important that you have modelled the search space correctly than to have used the most effective algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Genetic Algorithm can be, or can sometimes not be, the optimal or non-optimal solution.  Based on the complexity of the Genetic Algorithm, how much mutation there is, the forms of combinations, and how the chromosomes of the genetic algorithm is interpreted.

So, depending on how your AI is implemented, Genetic Algorithms can be the best.

You are looking at a SINGLE way to implement genetic algorithms, while forgetting about genetic programming, the use of math, higher-order functions, etc. Genetic algorithms can be EXTREMELY sophisticated, and by using clever combining systems for crossbreeding, extremely intelligent.
For instance, neural networks are optimized by genetic algorithms quite often.

---

Look up "Genetic Programming."  It's similar, but uses tree-structures instead of lines of characters, which allows for more complex interactions that breed better.  For more complex stuff, they typically work out better.

Answer (score 1):

There's been some research done using hierarchical reinforcement learning to build a layered ordering of actions that efficiently maximizes a reward. I haven't found much code implementing the idea, but there are a few papers describing MAXQ-based algorithms that have been used to explicitly tackle real-time strategy game domains, such as [this](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~bredeweg/pdf/BSc/20062007/Huizinga.pdf) and [this](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mehtane/papers/mash.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This Genetic algorithm only optimizes the strategy for one very specific part of the game: The order of the first few build actions of the game. And it has a very specific goal as well: To have as many roaches as quickly as possible.

The only aspects influencing this system seem to be (I'm no starcraft player):

- build time of the various units and
  buildings
- allowed units and buildings given the available units and buildings
- Larva regeneration rate.

This is a relatively limited, relatively well defined problem with a large search space. As such it is very well suited for genetic algorithms (and quite a few other optimization algorithm at that). A full gene is a specific set of build orders that ends in the 7th roach. From what I understand you can just "play" this specific gene to see how fast it finishes, so you have a very clear fitness test.
You also have a few nice constraints on the build order, so you can combine different genes slightly smarter than just randomly.

A genetic algorithm used in this way is a very good tool to find a more optimal build order for the first stage of a game of starcraft. Due to its random nature it is also good at finding a surprising strategy, which might have been an additional goal of the author.

To use a genetic algorithm as *the* algorithm in an RTS game you'd have to find a way to encode reactions to situations rather than just plain old build orders. This also involves correctly identifying situations which can be a difficult task in itself. Then you'd have to let these genes play thousands of games of starcraft, against each other and (possibly) against humans, selecting  and combining winners (or longer-lasting losers). This is also a good application of genetic algorithms, but it involves solving quite a few very hard problems before you even get to the genetic algorithm part.